# What is the difference between Richard Courant's "Differential and Integral Calculus" series and "Introduction to Calculus and Analysis"?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

What is the difference between the two series? Is there any that would be more rigorous, more aimed to applications, or any other thing?

Links:

Wikipedia page of Richard Courant with ISBNs, links to the books on archive.org, etc. : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Courant

Amazon page of volume I of "Introduction to Calculus and Analysis": [https://www.amazon.com/dp/354065058X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/354065058X)

Amazon page of Volume I of "Differential and Integral Calculus":[https://www.amazon.com/dp/4871878384](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/4871878384)

Comment: According to the preface of the 1965 "Introduction to Calculus and Analysis", it was re-written from the 1927 (German, 1934 English) "Differential and Integral Calculus" to be "more specifically directed at the needs of the present and future students in the United States". From the TOCs, I see more material in the later version, for example, a discussion of Induction. They both appear to be rigourous from what I can see. The 1965 preface suggests it supports applications, but the excerpts don't extend to those areas, so I cannot judge.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you, Paul.